# How to show a customizable view into all view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

the question is little bit elaborate what I really want to know.I want to make an app whose some functionality looks like SoundCloud and gaana. Below here I show some screenshot of gaana.

[image]

Here if we click any song they automatically update the above view and play the song and also this view will show into all view controller.Clicking this up arrow button how they showing up a new view where the previous small view is no where and also load a collection view into this new view.how to do all of this?the new view is here.

[image]

Comment: You could do that with a popover and set the anchor point as your button.

Comment: can you please explain me with some code and picture? It will help me a lot . I can pop over a view to click a button but my player keep in same place and also in this view i need to have a collection view to show the recommendation song.

Comment: https://makeapppie.com/tag/popover-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating an overlay, i.e. you add a `UIView` as a child element to the app's main `window` like so:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     showOverlay()
}


func showOverlay() {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {
        //if this block runs we were unable to get a reference to the main window
        print("you have probably called this method in viewDidLoad or at some earlier point where the main window reference might be nil")
        return
    }
    //add some custom view, for simplicity I've added a black view
    let blackView = UIView()
    blackView.backgroundColor = .black
    blackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    blackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height - 100, width: window.frame.width, height: 100.0)

    window.addSubview(blackView)
}
```

Now this view should always be floating above the current `UIViewController`

Comment: I can add this view using keywindow I know. but clicking the up button it make a new view where the previous view is gone.I can also do it programatically but the new window have a collection view or table view.The table view also showing properly but the datasource is not getting here. Cell for row at index path is not calling.why it happen I don't know.can you please test this and answer me? thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't quite understand your question. Can you please update your question with a more detailed description. Please also pay attention to the grammar.